# Share global variable across python modules

Tags: python

I'm trying to create global variable between two files
This is a snippet of the relevant code:

**Logger.py**

```
import globals
class Logger():
...
  def log(self): 
    globals.sql.execute('..')
```

**globals.py**

```
import Logger
import SQL

logger=Logger.Logger()
sql=SQL.SQL()
```

When running I get the error

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sql'

on `globals.sql.execute('..')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular import, `Logger` imports `globals` which imports `Logger`. Next, the `Logger.Logger()` line is run before the `sql=SQL.SQL()` line, so the latter *doesn't exist yet*.

Your code is otherwise not complete, but if you were to try and log anything from the `Logger.__init__()` method, that means the `globals` module *hasn't completed yet*, and you'll get your attribute error.

You could possibly remedy this by moving the `sql = SQL.SQL()` line to run *before* you create a `Logger()` instance. However, consider avoiding the circular import altogether.

You could pass in the `sql` object into the logger to avoid needing to create a circular import, for example.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to avoid circular import in this example?

Comment: @Kikapi: added; don't use `sql` as a global, pass it in as an argument to the logger.